# Change Telerik GricViewComboBox Append List Font

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, radgridview, datagridviewcombobox

i have a Telerik GridView with a ComboBox Column, while filtering in this Combobox an appending list dropped down.

Same as the image below...

[image]

So i want to make the font of the Append list larger.

How to do it?

Comment: have you checked the [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editor-fonts.html) documentation site, I am sure you will be able to find some examples. Also is there a Custom Font Property that you can set..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RadDropDownList uses different popups for its default items representation and for its auto complete suggest items. Here is an example demonstrating how to change the font of both:

```
 void radGridView1_CellEditorInitialized(object sender, GridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        RadDropDownListEditor editor = e.ActiveEditor as RadDropDownListEditor;
        if (editor != null)
        {
            editor.DropDownStyle = RadDropDownStyle.DropDown;
            RadDropDownListEditorElement element = (RadDropDownListEditorElement)editor.EditorElement;

            element.VisualItemFormatting -= element_VisualItemFormatting;
            element.AutoCompleteSuggest.DropDownList.VisualItemFormatting -= element_VisualItemFormatting;

            //this handles the default drop down formatting - when you press the arrow key to open the drop down
            element.VisualItemFormatting += element_VisualItemFormatting;
            //this handles the suggest popup formatting
            element.AutoCompleteSuggest.DropDownList.VisualItemFormatting += element_VisualItemFormatting;
        }
    }

    void element_VisualItemFormatting(object sender, VisualItemFormattingEventArgs args)
    {
        args.VisualItem.Font = new Font("Arial", 16);
    }
```

Comment: thank a lot it worked perfect. but i still have a question. How to increase the width of the suggest popup list. or how to make it fit to the longest string in the suggested popup list. Any of them could be fine. and thanks again!

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Here is how to set the minimum width of the suggest popup:                 element.AutoCompleteSuggest.DropDownList.DropDownMinSize = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 0);

To calculate the width of the longest item, you can use the TextRenderer.MeasureText method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.measuretext.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could either make a CellTemplate with your font, or you could handle the `CellFormating` event and do something like this:

```
void radGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, CellFormattingEventArgs  e)      
{ 
    // For all cells under the Account Name column
    if(e.CellElement.ColumnInfo.Name == "Account Name")
    {
        if(e.CellElement.Value != null)
        {
            System.Drawing.Font newfontsize = new System.Drawing.Font(e.CellElement.Font.FontFamily.Name,20);

            for each(GridViewCellInfo cell in e.Row.Cells)
            {
                e.CellElement.Font = newfontsize;
            }

        }
    }
    // For all other cells under other columns
    else
    {
        e.CellElement.ResetValue(Telerik.WinControls.UI.LightVisualElement.Font, Telerik.WinControls.ValueResetFlags.Local);
    }
}
```

Plug in whatever size font you want for the "newfontsize" variable. Also note that, the else statement may not be necessary in your case, but you can reset the font to default using the ResetValue property.

Comment: Thanks @glace for your help, but sorry it did not work at all and you misunderstood me. what I want is to enlarge the font in the dropped list. which is the list that pops down when i start typing (searching) inside the combobox. Not enlarging the font inside the cell...

Comment: Oh, my mistake. Can you access the underlying list attached to that event? Maybe cast the sender as a DataGridComboBoxCell (or something similar) then see if you can iterate through the ComboBox's list of items and change their formatting properties. I'll try to look into it some more if I get a chance.